# Extracting default field value from an object inside Option

Tags: scala

I have a class A, which contains an Option of class B(say b), which can be None. B has a string value(say str)inside it which I need  to extract and its default value is an empty string. So basically if b is None, I need to get empty string.

```
a.b.getOrElse(B).str
```

So, here I need to create an instance of B. Can this be avoided?

Comment: You mean that B has a different default value for its str argument and you want to use that value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes

```
val res = a.b.map(_.str).getOrElse("")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works for me. But if I don't know the default value then it may cause issues.

Comment: @Mandroid I'm not sure I understand your question. WDYM I don't know the default value?

Comment: Here I knew that default value of str is '' '', so we used that in getOrElse. If on other hand we are only told that we need to fetch str, but its default value is not known to us, hence we can't make use of it in getOrElse. I hope I am clear.

Comment: In the case you don't know the result of your return value, you need to use an `Option[A]` instead of returning an `A`. That way you're conveying that a value may not be found. That, or you can accept a `defaultValue` parameter in your method if applicable.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest and most efficient solution is to use `fold`:

```
a.b.fold("")(_.str)
```

The default value `""` could equally well be computed based on other values in `a`.

Using `map` then `getOrElse` means testing the `Option` value twice, whereas `fold` only tests once.